# Dynamic Programming: Rod cutting and remembering where cuts are made

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

So I have this code in python and currently it only returns the maximum value for cutting a rod. How can I modify this to also give me where the cuts were made? It takes a list of prices whose indices+1 correspond to the value of the rod at each length, and n, for length of the rod.

the problem:http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-rod-cutting.html

```
def cutRod(price, n):
    val = [0 for x in range(n+1)]
    val[0] = 0

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        max_val = 0
        for j in range(i):
            max_val = max(max_val, price[j] + val[i-j-1])
        val[i] = max_val

    return val[n]
```

Comment: Define "rod", "cutting". Give us a sample of list.

Comment: Say I have a rod of size 8, I want to cut this rod into pieces that have their own value such that I will profit the most from it. Let's say a rod of size 1 has a value of 1, size 2 has a value of 5, size 3 has a value of 8, size 4 has a value of 9, size 5 has a value of 10, size 6 has a value of 17, size 7 also has a value of 17, and size 8 has a value of 20. If I were to cut this rod into rods of length 2 and 6, I would have a total value of 22. So the list that would go in here would be [1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20]

Comment: Are you talking about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: This actually as someone else linked:http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-rod-cutting.html

Comment: Put that link in the question. It will help other peers. I am not going to cut rods. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If this is the question :  [Rod cutting](http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-rod-cutting.html)

Assuming code works fine, You will have to add a condition instead of Max operation to check which of two was picked and push that one in an array :

```
def cutRod(price, n):
    val = [0 for x in range(n+1)]
    val[0] = 0
    output = list()
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        max_val = 0
        cur_max_index = -1
        for j in range(i):
            cur_val = price[j] + val[i-j-1]
            if(cur_val>max_val):
                max_val = cur_val #store current max
                cur_max_index = j #and index
        if cur_max_index != -1:
            output.append(cur_max_index) #append in output index list
        val[i] = max_val
    print(output) #print array
    return val[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but just in case someone else has a look...I was actually just looking at this problem. I think the issue is here that these dp problems can be tricky when handling indices. The previous answer is not going to print the solution correctly simply because this line needs to be adjusted...

`cur_max_index = j` which should be `cur_max_index = j + 1`

The rest...

```
def cut_rod(prices, length):
    values = [0] * (length + 1)
    cuts = [-1] * (length + 1)
    max_val = -1
    for i in range(1, length + 1):
        for j in range(i):
            temp = prices[j] + values[i - j - 1] 
            if temp > max_val:
                max_val = prices[j] + values[i - j - 1]
                cuts[i] = j + 1
        values[i] = max_val
    return values[length], cuts


def print_cuts(cuts, length):
    while length > 0:
        print(cuts[length], end=" ")
        length -= cuts[length]

max_value, cuts = cut_rod(prices, length)
print(max_value)
print_cuts(cuts, length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to get the actual pieces that would be the result of this process then you'd probably need a recursion.

For example something like that:

```
def cutRod(price, n):
val = [0 for x in range(n + 1)]
pieces = [[0, 0]]
val[0] = 0

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    max_val = 0
    max_pieces = [0, 0]
    for j in range(i):
      curr_val = price[j] + val[i - j - 1]
      if curr_val > max_val:
        max_val = curr_val
        max_pieces = [j + 1, i - j - 1]
    pieces.append(max_pieces)
    val[i] = max_val

arr = []

def f(left, right):
  if right == 0:
    arr.append(left)
    return
  f(pieces[left][0], pieces[left][1])
  f(pieces[right][0], pieces[right][1])

f(pieces[n][0], pieces[n][1])

return val[n], arr
```

In this code, there is an additional array for pieces which represents the best way to divide our Rod with some length.
Besides, there is a function f that goes through all pieces and figures out the optimal way to divide the whole Rod.